# Derivative of a postion vector of a point P that moves along a given curve.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vectors, curves

I'm reading through a section of Alan Jeffery's book *Mathematics for Engineers and Scientists*. In particular the derivative of a vector function, the context of the analysis is a position vector of a point $\mathbf{u}(t)$ which is a function of $t$ (say, time) that moves along a given curve.

[Photo Page 1 of book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EW0DO.jpg)

[Photo Page 2 of book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUqeO.jpg)

The section of the book proves/shows that the the instantaneous speed (i.e the scalar rate of change of distance along the curve) is the magnitude of the the vector $\mathrm{d}\mathbf{u}/\mathrm{d}t$.

I follow the analysis up until equation eqn (11.5) I can't understand how that equation is obtained from the preceding one (which un-numbered).

Other online notes arrive at the same result without equation 11.5.  Could some explain how eqn 11.5 on page 2 is obtained from the immediately preceding line.

Some of the questions I've seen are humblingly rarefied, so apologize for my simple one !

Comment: Dividing by $(dt)^2$ and taking the square root from both sides. Your book doen't appear to be very rigorous, but you can make it more rigorous by considering $\Delta s$ and $\Delta t$ whenever there is $ds$ and $dt$ and taking the limit subsequently. Welcome to MSE.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I was wondering about dividing by dt since it should not be treated as an algebraic quantity, so if delta s and delta were used it would make more sense.

Comment: Thankyou. Issue solved.